# Самохостинг через dlinkddns.com

Tags: javascript, html, css

Приостоновил создание сайта в теплом и уютном denvere. Начал изучать вопрос хостинга. Думаю пока я новичок и не известно как мое творение будет выглядеть на волнах инета, решил хостится сам через бесплатный dlinkddns. URL получил, роутер настроил. Осталось: 1) настроить комп и куда-то положить свой сайт чтобы стал виден; 2) сайт работает с SQL, куда выкладывать базу? 3) html у меня лежит рядом с папками css php js. Как защитить папки от просмотра и вообще общие вопросы безопасности сайта?

Comment: На роутере настройте dmz на айпи компа, компа выдайте статика в рамках сети.

Comment: Я бы на Вашем месте просто воспользовался бесплатным хостингом.  У Вас кроме обычных проблем добавились еще проблемы с dlinkddns. Возьмите бесплатный хостинг и закройте сайт от индексации

Comment: Спасибо, хороший совет Vyacheslav Potseluyko. По-любому буду переходить на платный хороший хостинг - изучаю вопрос. Мне бы только взглянуть как выглядит сайт снаружи может рано еще выходить в свет... Интересно иосы и андроиды видят сайты также как в винде или какие-то примочки нужно цеплять?

Comment: мдаа, чет думал завалят помощью ))